# partially mocking a class without affecting the private properties in PHP

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I have a class with a lot of methods in which I need to mock only one method due to some sql incompatibility between mysql and in-memory sqlite database.

```
class OrderService implements OrderServiceContract
{
    protected $deliveryService;

    public function __construct(Delivery $deliveryService) // DI injected object
    {
        ...
        $this->deliveryService = $deliveryService;
        ...
    }

    public function methodNeedstoBeMocked() 
    {
      ....some sql related code...
    }

    public function returnToWarehouse($orderId) 
    {
      DB::transaction(function() use ($orderId) {
         ...
         $this->deliveryService->someOtherMethod($orderId); // problematic external service call 
         ...
      });
    }

}
```

Now in my test I partially mock this class according to [this doc link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mocking#mocking-objects), and I call the `returnToWarehouse` from test but then it says that

> Error : Call to a member function returnToWarehouse() on null.

meaning that the property `$deliveryService` doesn't exist on mock.

My test Implementation is as follows.

```
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function an_order_can_be_returned_to_warehouse()
    {
        ...
        ...
        $this->partialMock(OrderService::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('methodNeedstoBeMocked')->andReturn(collect([]));
        });

        $orderService = app(OrderService::class);

        $orderService->markOrderReturnedToWarehouse($order->id); // here is the problem gets triggered.
        ...
        //assertions
    }
```

What might be going wrong here? and what are some ways to mitigate this? Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that partial test doubles from Mockery do not call the original constructor. For more information, please read the documentation [here](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/not_calling_the_constructor.html).

Alternatively, you could consider mocking the "problematic" method a bit differently. For example, you could extract that logic to a **repository** (since you mention that it is dealing with the database layer) that can then be mocked during your test.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, When I have to mock some third party services I set up a Mock Like this.

This way you can set up easily your DI services

```
<?php
if (app()->environment('testing')) {

            $this->app->bind(Delivery::class, static function () {

                $service = \Mockery::mock(Delivery::class);

                $service->shouldReceive('someOtherMethod')->andReturn([]);

                return $service;
            });

        }
```

Comment: But isnt it mocking the DeliveryService? What I am doing is mocking the OrderService class. Also where do suggest i put this? Inside the code base or the test case itself?

Comment: Hi I think you should Mock the DeliveryService too, but Maybe I am wrong, I suggest to add that code on your setUp Method in your TestClass